# Wordpress attachment urls as variables

Tags: wordpress, attachment

My posts have 3 images attached, I want to turn the 3 image urls into 3 separate variables and use them background images in `css`. So far I have been able to display the 3 urls, but cannot turn them into variables so I can call them as background image.

```
if ($attachments = get_children(array(
              'post_type' => 'attachment',
              'post_mime_type' => 'image',
              'numberposts' => -1,
              'post_status' => null,
              'post_parent' => $post->ID
                  )));

          foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {

              $mynewarray = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment->ID, 'rig');
              $anotherarray = $mynewarray[0];
              echo $anotherarray ;
          }
```

The result of above is [here](http://www.test-dev.dev/wp-content/uploads/post3image3.jpghttp://www.test-dev.dev/wp-content/uploads/post3image2.jpghttp://www.test-dev.dev/wp-content/uploads/post3image1.jpg).

How can I separate these and turn them into variables, like `$backgroundimage1, $backgroundimage2 & $backgroundimage3`. So i can call them later in page, like below

```
<div class="backgound-image" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $backgroundimage1 ?>)">
```

Comment: opps thanks for help, will improve my formatting for next time, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can add all attachments to new array. And get indexes from array same you want.

```
if ($attachments = get_children(array(
              'post_type' => 'attachment',
              'post_mime_type' => 'image',
              'numberposts' => -1,
              'post_status' => null,
              'post_parent' => $post->ID
                  )));

          $mynewarray = array();
          foreach ($attachments as $attachment) {

              $mynewarray = wp_get_attachment_image_src($attachment->ID, 'rig');
              $anotherarray[] = $mynewarray[0];
              // echo $anotherarray ;
              // not echo, only define in here
          }
```

After defination, you can get these.

```
echo $mynewarray[0]; // or [1] or [2]
```

Comment: Wow, great. 8 hrs searching net for solution. Took 5 mins to write post here and answer solving problem in less than 10, THanks so much Fatih Sari

Comment: @Stephen please do not forget to accept answer. 
http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251078/how-to-update-and-accept-answers